# Calling onActivityResult in NestedFragment (View Pager)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've an ImageView in one of my tab (Fragment) of view pager that is included in my Activity. I'm trying to load an image from a gallery but seems like onActivityResult is being called of the Parent Activity. I've searched and tried many solutions but none of them worked. The closest approach made was with writing this:

In Parent Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In Parent Fragment:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    List<Fragment> fragments = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

And in child fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), LOAD_IMAGE_GALLARY);





   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_GALLARY) {


            if (data != null) {

                picUri = data.getData();
                CropImage();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE) {


            if (data != null) {
                // get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                // get the cropped bitmap
                photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                flat_photo.setImageBitmap(photo);

                if (pic != null) {
                    // To delete original image taken by camera
                    if (pic.delete()) {


                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


protected void CropImage() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");

        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 4);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
        intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);


        getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_IMAGE);


    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                "Sorry, your device don't support cropping.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

What happens in this code is, the crop window appears when I'm done with the cropping and press submit, it appears again and after that pressing submit finishes the activity. In short, it doesn't work.

There are hundreds of solution posted by several users. Please try writing a working one. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In Parent Activity with ViewPager:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

And in child fragment of ViewPager:

```
@OnClick(R.id.fabNav)
public void showComposePost(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ComposeActivity.class);
    /*[...]*/
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,1888);
}
```

in the same child fragment:

```
@override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "reqCode: " + requestCode);
    Log.d(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1888) {
        getList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult`() will always be called out in the Activity. It will never return result in a Fragment. What you can do is once you get the result in the Activity, you can pass the result to a fragment which is what you have posted in your question itself.

```
fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Where fragment is the instance of the Fragment to which the result should be passed.